# how to perform machine learning multiple regression on csv file data using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have to write the code for a general case for any csv file as input with any no of variables and records. 
I've started this way.How do i continue?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def get_data(file_name):
data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
para = int(raw_input('Enter the no of parameters to be used '))
print(para)
param= []
for k in range(0,para-1):
        param[k]= raw_input('Enter the parameter')

rec = int(raw_input('Enter the no of records in the dataset '))
print(rec)
x_parameter = []
y_parameter = []
x1= []
for i in range(0,para):
    for x1[i] in data[i]:
        x_parameter[i].append(x1[i])

for j in range(0,rec):
    print x_parameter[j]
    print y_parameter[j]

get_data('C:\Python27\data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you not encode the parameter names in the csv file. You can just them as headers for the column and pandas will automatically assign them correctly. Next you can use len(data) to get the amount of samples instead of having to type this.

For Linear Regression you will have to fill in the y_parameter or at least split it away from pandas. Then you can use scikit-learn to apply Linear Regression as described here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Code Example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_parameter, y_parameter)
```

Comment: But i want this to be a general code i.e it should work for any file that the user passes as a parameter to the function.

Comment: My answer also works for this case. You can still pass in your objects into the linear regression model.

Comment: But what if the user has multiple input features?Then the linear regression model will not work. Multiple regression would be needed. How do i do that?

Comment: Linear Regression works for abritrary amount features. You just have to pass in a Matrix which responds to your feature vectors. The shape would be like this (Nr. Samples, Nr. features)

Comment: But how would the test and train samples be split?